# TreeView in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Is there a way to show tree-like structure and may be fill it in InfoPath. I googled so much but didn't find any answer. Share link if you could. Solution may use Sharepoint.

P.S.

I totally new in this technology so I even don't know right terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get a tree-like interface effect is to use buttons and formatting rules to create collapsible sections by hiding them conditionally.

For example you have a plus button and a minus button next to each other. The plus button sets a ShowSection field to 1, the minus button sets it to 0. When the field value is 0, rules hide the section and the minus button. When the value is 1, a rule hides the plus button. The end user experience is to press the plus button to see what's below it, and press the minus to make it disappear.

The tree effect comes when you start putting one collapsible section inside another recursively.